# Adding custom columns to custom post types

Tags: wp-admin, columns

I've done this previously but I've forgotten the name of the hook, and can't find it anywhere...

What I'm trying to do is add some custom columns in the listing of a custom post type in the admin.

For example, in the admin, click on *articles*, I want to add custom column there.

Comment: i asked (and answered) the same question (including how to make them sortable): http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/253680/add-custom-column-to-custom-post-type-overview-in-backend

Answer (score 133, accepted):

The hooks to create custom columns and their associated data for a custom post type are `manage_{$post_type}_posts_columns` and  [`manage_{$post_type}_posts_custom_column`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_posts_custom_column) respectively, where `{$post_type}` is the name of the custom post type.

This example from the documentation removes the author column and adds a taxonomy and meta data column:

```
// Add the custom columns to the book post type:
add_filter( 'manage_book_posts_columns', 'set_custom_edit_book_columns' );
function set_custom_edit_book_columns($columns) {
    unset( $columns['author'] );
    $columns['book_author'] = __( 'Author', 'your_text_domain' );
    $columns['publisher'] = __( 'Publisher', 'your_text_domain' );

    return $columns;
}

// Add the data to the custom columns for the book post type:
add_action( 'manage_book_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_book_column', 10, 2 );
function custom_book_column( $column, $post_id ) {
    switch ( $column ) {

        case 'book_author' :
            $terms = get_the_term_list( $post_id , 'book_author' , '' , ',' , '' );
            if ( is_string( $terms ) )
                echo $terms;
            else
                _e( 'Unable to get author(s)', 'your_text_domain' );
            break;

        case 'publisher' :
            echo get_post_meta( $post_id , 'publisher' , true ); 
            break;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this hook!!! This is brilliant!! There's no clear documentation on stackoverflow!!! :D Cheers mate

Comment: isn't there any option to set the column number? like `column_index[2]`. Because the custom_column appears at the end of the column.

Comment: @DilipGupta $columns is an array, you can reorder before you return it

Comment: In the case of adding a taxonomy term column. How would you add a link below the term name that would Filter the table to that term? I have seen this on a few plugins before.

Comment: @iamonstage `register_taxonomy()` now has support for that built in via the `show_admin_column` setting passed via 
 arguments. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/. If you aren't registering the taxonomy yourself, you can still alter the args via the `register_taxonomy_args` filter https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/register_taxonomy_args/

Answer (score 16):

I wrote a function that combines `manage_{$post_type}_posts_columns` filter and `manage_{$post_type}_posts_custom_column` action.

EDIT: Added column sorting filter `manage_edit-{$post_type}_sortable_columns` and `pre_get_posts` action.

```
function add_admin_column( $column_title, $post_type, $cb, $order_by = false, $order_by_field_is_meta = false ){

    // Column Header
    add_filter( 'manage_' . $post_type . '_posts_columns', function( $columns ) use ($column_title) {
        $columns[ sanitize_title($column_title) ] = $column_title;
        return $columns;
    } );

    // Column Content
    add_action( 'manage_' . $post_type . '_posts_custom_column' , function( $column, $post_id ) use ($column_title, $cb) {
        if( sanitize_title($column_title) === $column)
          $cb($post_id);
    }, 10, 2 );

    // OrderBy Set?
    if( !empty( $order_by ) ) {

      // Column Sorting
      add_filter( 'manage_edit-' . $post_type . '_sortable_columns', function ( $columns ) use ($column_title, $order_by) {
          $columns[ sanitize_title($column_title) ] = $order_by;
          return $columns;
      } );

      // Column Ordering
      add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $query ) use ($order_by, $order_by_field_is_meta) {
          if( ! is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() )
            return;

          if ( sanitize_key($order_by) === $query->get( 'orderby') ) {
              if($order_by_field_is_meta){
                  $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
                  $query->set( 'meta_key', sanitize_key($order_by) );
              }
              else {
                  $query->set( 'orderby', sanitize_key($order_by) );
              }
          }
      } );
  
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
add_admin_column(__('EAN'), 'product', function($post_id){
    echo get_post_meta( $post_id , 'ean' , true ); 
}, 'meta_key_name', true);
```

The `meta_key_name` can be omitted to avoid sorting. Otherwise, you will need to know your exact meta_key name for sorting to work properly.

```
add_admin_column(__('Last Modified'), 'post', function($post_id){
    echo get_the_modified_date(); 
}, 'modified');
```

In this case, `modified` isn't a meta key.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you. How can I manage to get the newly created column sortable?

Comment: Try this article in Smashing Magazine https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/12/customizing-admin-columns-wordpress/

Comment: Doing these things is where you find the wordpress POWER... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it default custom meta data that you want to show as columns, but you could consider to use this free plugin that allows you to add columns to display custom fields. https://wordpress.org/plugins/codepress-admin-columns/

The pro version even allows you to add filtering, sorting and inline edit to those columns.

Comment: DO NOT USE! Will break your site:
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare AC() (previously declared in [redacted]\\wp-content\\themes\\[redacted]\\functions.php:628) in [redacted]\\wp-content\\plugins\\codepress-admin-columns\\api.php on line 9

Comment: @PeterKionga-Kamau this is a compatibility-issue with your specific theme. The error you posted will not appear with a default WP theme (such as twentytwenty); I also use the plugin with the Divi Theme and find it quite useful

Comment: Isn't there some kind of namespacing or use of less generic function names that could be used to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on Carlos response (thank you very much)
I wanted to add a little thumbnail image, but not a featured one, one from custom metabox.

So this is what I added:

```
add_admin_column(__('Thumbnail'), 'obraz', function($post_id){
$image_id =  get_post_meta( $post_id , 'custom_thumbnail_metabox' , true );
echo '<img src="'.wp_get_attachment_image_url($image_id).'" />';
```

Info:
the post meta will get the ID of the attachment/image so thats the reason for later call of wp_get_attachment_image_url

Answer (score 0):

For woocommerce orders I needed to use the filter: manage_edit-shop_order_columns.

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'manage_shop_order_posts_columns', 10, 1 );
function manage_shop_order_posts_columns($columns) {
    $columns['test'] = 'Test';
    return $columns;
}
```

Then to populate the field:

```
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'manage_shop_order_custom_column', 10, 2 );
function manage_shop_order_custom_column($column, $post_id) {
    switch ( $column )
    {
        case 'test' :
            echo '1234';
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This [guide](https://www.ractoon.com/wordpress-sortable-admin-columns-for-custom-posts/) worked for me. In my case, I'm using [CPT UI](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) to create the custom post types, [ACF](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) to create the custom post fields, and [Code Snippets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/) to glue everything together.

I've included a simplified version of the code below.

Change `custom-post-type-slug`, `custom_post_type_slug`, and `custom_column_name` below to suit your needs. Be sure to maintain the same dash/underscore format when changing the names.

Note that [`get_field()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) is specific to the ACF plugin. If you're not using ACF, you may want to use the built-in [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) WordPress function to retrieve and display post metadata.

```php
add_filter('manage_custom-post-type-slug_posts_columns', 'set_custom_edit_custom_post_type_slug_columns');

function set_custom_edit_custom_post_type_slug_columns($columns) {
    $columns['custom_column_name'] = 'Custom Column Title';
    return $columns;
}

add_action('manage_custom-post-type-slug_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_custom_post_type_slug_column', 10, 2);

function custom_custom_post_type_slug_column($column, $post_id) {
    switch ($column) {
        case 'custom_column_name':
            echo get_field('custom_column_name', $post_id);
            break;
    }
}

add_filter('manage_edit-custom-post-type-slug_sortable_columns', 'set_custom_custom_post_type_slug_sortable_columns');

function set_custom_custom_post_type_slug_sortable_columns($columns) {
    $columns['custom_column_name'] = 'custom_column_name';
    return $columns;
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_post_type_slug_custom_orderby');

function custom_post_type_slug_custom_orderby($query) {
    if ( ! is_admin()) {
        return;
    }

    $orderby = $query->get('orderby');

    if ('custom_column_name' == $orderby) {
        $query->set('meta_key', 'custom_column_name');
        $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
    }
}
```