# Add custom column to custom post type overview in backend

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, admin, columns

I have a custom post type called *events*. In the backend/administration I can list all these custom post types, that is, *events*:

[image]

As you can see, there are three columns in this overview: *Title*, *Tags*, and *Date*. Each of these *events* has a custom field named *eventDate*.

My question now is, how can I add a sortable *eventDate* column to the *events* overview (pictured above)?

Comment: okay, i just found this link: http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/add-custom-column/ BUT how can i make the column sortable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, I found an answer myself. To help people who will read this in future, this is what I did:

1) This explains how to add a column: http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/add-custom-column/

2) This explains how to add a sortable column: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/admin-column-sorting/

Answer (score 4):

The hooks to create custom columns and their associated data for a custom post type are manage_{$post_type}_posts_columns and  manage_{$post_type}_posts_custom_column respectively, where {$post_type} is the name of the custom post type.

This example from the documentation removes the author column and adds a taxonomy and meta data column:

```
// Add the custom columns to the book post type:
    add_filter( 'manage_book_posts_columns', 'set_custom_edit_book_columns' );
    function set_custom_edit_book_columns($columns) {
        unset( $columns['author'] );
        $columns['book_author'] = __( 'Author', 'your_text_domain' );
        $columns['publisher'] = __( 'Publisher', 'your_text_domain' );

        return $columns;
    }

    // Add the data to the custom columns for the book post type:
    add_action( 'manage_book_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_book_column', 10, 2 );
    function custom_book_column( $column, $post_id ) {
        switch ( $column ) {

            case 'book_author' :
                $terms = get_the_term_list( $post_id , 'book_author' , '' , ',' , '' );
                if ( is_string( $terms ) )
                    echo $terms;
                else
                    _e( 'Unable to get author(s)', 'your_text_domain' );
                break;

            case 'publisher' :
                echo get_post_meta( $post_id , 'publisher' , true ); 
                break;

        }
    }
```

Copied from existing ans.

Comment: is the column sortable?

Comment: no these colums won't be sortable..you have to make it sortable..

Answer (score 4):

Here is the entire code for this:

```
add_filter('manage_edit-video_columns', 'my_columns');
function my_columns($columns) {
    $columns['eventDate'] = 'Event Date';
    return $columns;
}

add_action('manage_posts_custom_column',  'my_show_columns');
function my_show_columns($name) {
    global $post;
    switch ($name) {
        case 'eventDate':
            $eventDate = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'eventDate', true);
            echo $eventDate;
    }
}

add_filter( 'manage_edit-video_sortable_columns', 'my_sortable_date_column' );
function my_sortable_date_column( $columns ) {
    $columns['eventDate'] = 'Event Date';

    return $columns;
}
```

Thanks