# How to customize custom post type's list table?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-list-table

I have created a custom post type and here's

[image]

I'd like to remove the title and add several custom post meta instead, but how do i customize my custom post type's existing list table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your answer is on this post: [Adding custom columns to custom post types](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/253640/adding-custom-columns-to-custom-post-types) and here is a complete "How to": https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/12/customizing-admin-columns-wordpress/

Comment: The second link worked perfectly for my needs. Thank you very much!!